# What's the "money" tag for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

Since June, 2014, the excerpt for the [money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) tag has been:

> Questions pertaining to different types of currencies and the mechanics of currency in general, pertaining to Jewish Law.

However, of the ten top-scoring questions bearing this tag, very few fit this description:

- [What do you do if you made a Tzedaka pledge and now the organization folded?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14169/what-do-you-do-if-you-made-a-tzedaka-pledge-and-now-the-organization-folded) (Finance)
- [Does Jewish Law Recognize Bankruptcy?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13320/does-jewish-law-recognize-bankruptcy)  (Finance)
- [Train ticket not collected: destroy?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12180/train-ticket-not-collected-destroy) (Choshen Mishpat)
- [Can I lend out a Library Book?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9744/can-i-lend-out-a-library-book) (Choshen Mishpat)
- [Why must prophets be wealthy?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12751/why-must-prophets-be-wealthy) (Finance)
- [Wearing a kippa at work](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/wearing-a-kippa-at-work) (Making a living)
- [Is flipping a coin following an omen?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35425/is-flipping-a-coin-following-an-omen) (Currency)
- [Do our sources address "strategic loan defaults"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/284/do-our-sources-address-strategic-loan-defaults) (Finance)
- [Bitcoin and Halakha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25954/bitcoin-and-halakha) (Currency)
- [Giving Tzedakah with a Credit Card](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9929/giving-tzedakah-with-a-credit-card) (Finance)

I've marked each with the primary way I see them connecting to the topic of "money":

- 5 have to do with financial concepts.
- 2 have to do with currency.
- 2 have to do with Choshen Mishpat but not necessarily finance directly.
- 1 has to do with making a living, but not necessarily finance directly.

Admittedly, this is a small and possibly popularity-biased sample of a tag that currently has 205 posts. It fits, though, with my sense of what this word means and what this tag generally is used for: money, generally, including spending, earning, and handling it.

I think that this concept is distinct from that of [choshen-mishpat-civil-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choshen-mishpat-civil-law) even though there is significant overlap, in that "money" includes purely currency-oriented questions like the coin-flipping one or handling currency on Shabbat, as well as questions about Tzedaka and status based on personal wealth. Choshen Mishpat, on the other hand, includes questions that don't really have to do with money, such as the two labeled "Choshen Mishpat," above.

What should we do with this tag? Should we change its writeup? Should we change what questions it's applied to? Should we split it up or create any aliases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that we ought to:

- Rewrite the excerpt and summary to make the tag about money, generally, including currency and finances.
- Explain in the summaries of both [money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) and [choshen-mishpat-civil-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choshen-mishpat-civil-law) how they're distinct.
- Remove [money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) from questions that are about Ch"M [or employment](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3830/2), but not about finances or currency, *per se*. If those questions don't already have the appropriate parallel tags, apply them.
- Consider adding aliases for [money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money): "finance" and "currency".

---

**Implemented:**

About a week after this answer and Scimonster's were posted, seeing approval and no dissent, I implemented most of the suggestions. I did the tag summary work suggested above. I removed [money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) from a bunch of questions on which it does not belong, according to these suggestions and my estimation; I did not go looking for questions that aren't yet tagged [money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money), [choshen-mishpat-civil-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choshen-mishpat-civil-law), vel sim., but should be. I did not add aliases, as it's messy for non-mods to do so *ab initio*.

msh210 added [currency](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) as a synonym of [money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) and suggested [finance](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) as a synonym. The latter will take effect if four users with [the appropriate privilege](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) visit [money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money)'s [synonyms page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/money/synonyms) and upvote the suggested synonym.

Comment: I have added [tag:currency] and [suggested](//judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) [tag:finance] as synonyms for [tag:money].

Comment: @msh210 incorporated; thanks. Why add one and suggest the other?

Comment: I wasn't sure about the other. ''Finance'' means not only finances generally but investments specifically. I wouldn't have suggested it, either, tbh, but for the votes on this post. But [44 users](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/420487/who-can-vote-on-synonyms-for-a-given-tag?TagName=money#resultSets) can vote on that synonym suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

> 1 has to do with making a living, but not necessarily finance directly.

That doesn't really seem to be a fit for [money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money). The question you mentioned already has [employment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment). I think that's enough for it.

Of course, that doesn't mean that other [[employment+money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment+money)] questions can't be tagged with both.